# Vector Subscript out of Range During Projectile Creation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

There are two Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library messages that pop up when I attempt to create projectiles while my game is running

```
Debug Assertion Failed! Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
12.0\vc\include\vector Line:1201 Expression: vector subscript out of range
```

and

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: C:\SFML-2.3.2\SFML\Debug\SFML.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector
Line:1202
Expression: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0
```

and then a message for Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5B89A893 (msvcr120d.dll) in SFML.exe: An
>   invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid
>   parameters fatal.

This occurs as soon as I press the space bar to create a projectile (green square). The green square appears on the screen where it should and then the message immediately pops up. The projectile at this point with current code should behave as a green square paint brush, but this message pops up. Here is my source code:

### main:

```
int main ( )

{
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int counter3 = 0;

//create the main window

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Demo");

sf::Event event;

sf::Vector2i source(1, 0);

//load texture

sf::Texture texturePlayer;

if (!texturePlayer.loadFromFile("images/player.png"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

//class object
class player Player1;
Player1.sprite.setTexture(texturePlayer);

//Projectile vector array
vector<projectile>::const_iterator iter;
vector<projectile> projectileArray;

//projectile object

class projectile projectile1;


while ( window.isOpen() )
{
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if ( event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed )
            window.close();
    }
    window.clear();

    //fire missile (space bar)
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
    {
        projectile1.rect.setPosition(Player1.rect.getPosition());
        projectileArray.push_back(projectile1);
    }

    //Draw projectile
    for (iter = projectileArray.begin(); iter != projectileArray.end(); iter++)
    {
        window.draw(projectileArray[counter1].rect);
        counter1++;
    }


    //update player with rectangle collision detection
    Player1.update();  
    Player1.updateMovement();


    //window.draw(Player1.rect);
    window.draw(Player1.sprite);
    window.display();


 }

}
```

### projectile.h

class projectile: public entity   //inheriting from entity
{
public:

```
float movementSpeed = 10;
int attackDamage = 5;

projectile();               //constructor
//void update();
//void updateMovement();
};
```

#endif

### projectile.cpp

```
    projectile::projectile() {

rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10.0, 10.0));

rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

rect.setPosition(0, 0);

//sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 32, 32)); }
```

How do I fix this? Any advice/help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I initialized the counter at the beginning of main but with that code it now works thank you thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cycle `Draw projectile` You must use or iterator for to access for elements in `projectileArray` like this

```
for (iter = projectileArray.begin(); iter != projectileArray.end(); iter++)
{
    window.draw(iter->rect);
}
```

or initialize `counter1=0;` before cycle otherwise in second iteration of main `while` `counter1` will not be point on begin of vector `projectileArray`.